# VSTO Office Addin opens WinForm that needs Administrator Rights for HKLM Access

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, excel-addins, elevated-privileges

I have developed a rather big Excel VSTO Addin in C# in Visual Studio.
Among other things it installs a button onto the Ribbon and when the user clicks it, it opens a Windows Form. This form and the main addin are both part of the same project.
The addin is installed through a Windows-Installer not ClickOnce.

The user then is prompted by the form for an input.

The Form then creates a key in HKLM and sets its value depending on the input of the user.

But since you need Administrator Privileges to write to HKLM it doesn't work.
I would like to prompt the user for Administrator Privileges when opening the form.

It is important that I don't want the whole addin or Excel to run elevated, but only said Windows Form.

Is there any way to achieve this?

For reference, this is the code of the button in the ribbon:

```
myform form1 = new myform();
form1.ShowDialog();
```

And this is the relevant code of the form:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pathtokey, true);
key.SetValue("input", textBox1.Text.ToString());
key.Close();
```

Comment: Youre unwilling to use HKCU?

Comment: the scenario is that I want the admin to enter a license key that gets written to HKLM so that every user of that machine is licensed

Comment: Can you use the application settings for this?